# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build,showing widget error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Trying to build Quiz App but i m getting  setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error.
This widget caanot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:my_thera/screens/client/assess/quiz.dart';
        import 'package:my_thera/screens/client/assess/result.dart';
        
        class MyAp extends StatefulWidget {
          const MyAp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
            return _MyApState();
          }
        }
        
        class _MyApState extends State<MyAp> {
          final _questions = const [
            {
              'questionText': 'Q1. Who created Flutter?',
              'answers': [
                {'text': 'Facebook', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Adobe', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Google', 'score': 10},
                {'text': 'Microsoft', 'score': -2},
              ],
            },
            {
              'questionText': 'Q2. What is Flutter?',
              'answers': [
                {'text': 'Android Development Kit', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'IOS Development Kit', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Web Development Kit', 'score': -2},
                {
                  'text':
                      'SDK to build beautiful IOS, Android, Web & Desktop Native Apps',
                  'score': 10
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              'questionText': ' Q3. Which programing language is used by Flutter',
              'answers': [
                {'text': 'Ruby', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Dart', 'score': 10},
                {'text': 'C++', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Kotlin', 'score': -2},
              ],
            },
            {
              'questionText': 'Q4. Who created Dart programing language?',
              'answers': [
                {'text': 'Lars Bak and Kasper Lund', 'score': 10},
                {'text': 'Brendan Eich', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Bjarne Stroustrup', 'score': -2},
                {'text': 'Jeremy Ashkenas', 'score': -2},
              ],
            },
            {
              'questionText':
                  'Q5. Is Flutter for Web and Desktop available in stable version?',
              'answers': [
                {
                  'text': 'Yes',
                  'score': -2,
                },
                {'text': 'No', 'score': 10},
              ],
            },
          ];
        
          var _questionIndex = 0;
          var _totalScore = 0;
        
          void _resetQuiz() {
            setState(() {
              _questionIndex = 0;
              _totalScore = 0;
            });
          }
        
          void _answerQuestion(int score) {
            _totalScore += score;
        
            setState(() {
              _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
            });
            // ignore: avoid_print
            print(_questionIndex);
            if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print('We have more questions!');
            } else {
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print('No more questions!');
            }
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Quiz'),
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF00E676),
              ),
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: _questionIndex < _questions.length
                    ? Quiz(
                        answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
                        questionIndex: _questionIndex,
                        questions: _questions,
                      ) //Quiz
                    : Result(_totalScore, _resetQuiz),
              ), //Padding
            ); //Scaffold
            //MaterialApp
          }
        }
```

Quiz part:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_thera/screens/client/assess/answer.dart';
import 'package:my_thera/screens/client/assess/question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  const Quiz({
    Key? key,
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestion,
    required this.questionIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
        ), //Question
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(
              () => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'].toString());
        }).toList()
      ],
    ); //Column
  }
}
```

Result part:

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  final int resultScore;
  final Function resetHandler;

  const Result(this.resultScore, this.resetHandler, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

//Remark Logic
  String get resultPhrase {
    String resultText;
    if (resultScore >= 41) {
      resultText = 'You are awesome!';
      print(resultScore);
    } else if (resultScore >= 31) {
      resultText = 'Pretty likeable!';
      print(resultScore);
    } else if (resultScore >= 21) {
      resultText = 'You need to work more!';
    } else if (resultScore >= 1) {
      resultText = 'You need to work hard!';
    } else {
      resultText = 'This is a poor score!';
      print(resultScore);
    }
    return resultText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            resultPhrase,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ), //Text
          Text(
            'Score ' '$resultScore',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ), //Text
          TextButton(
            onPressed: resetHandler(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
              child: const Text(
                'Restart Quiz',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // FlatButton is deprecated and should not be used
          // Use TextButton instead

          // FlatButton(
          // child: Text(
          //     'Restart Quiz!',
          // ), //Text
          // textColor: Colors.blue,
          // onPressed: resetHandler(),
          // ), //FlatButton
        ], //<Widget>[]
      ), //Column
    ); //Center
  }
}
```

answer part:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  const Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use SizedBox for white space instead of Container
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: selectHandler(),
        style: ButtonStyle(
            textStyle:
                MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
        child: Text(answerText),
      ),

      // RaisedButton is deprecated and should not be used
      // Use ElevatedButton instead

      // child: RaisedButton(
      // color: const Color(0xFF00E676),
      // textColor: Colors.white,
      // onPressed: selectHandler(),
      // child: Text(answerText),
      // ), //RaisedButton
    ); //Container
  }
}
```

question part:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Question extends StatelessWidget {
      final String questionText;
    
      const Question(this.questionText, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text(
            questionText,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ), //Text
        ); //Contaier
      }

}
```

Trying to build Quiz App but i m getting  setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error.This widget caanot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.

Comment: Can you include `Quiz` part

Comment: Seems ok to me, can you include `Result` part

Comment: Sorry I should've consider this, are `Question` and `Answer` any of it is stateFullWidget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh added all can u check :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with `Answer` section. `onPressed: selectHandler(),` is calling the parent state to rebuild and occurring the issue. It can done by `onPressed: selectHandler,`

But `onPressed` accept  `VoidCallback`

```dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler; //this
  final String answerText;

  const Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Container
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: selectHandler, //this
        style: ButtonStyle(
            textStyle:
                MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
        child: Text(answerText),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Same goes for `Result`

Comment: at end of last question is answered i m again getting the same error.

Comment: Change the same for `Result` widget, if you failed, let me know

Comment: i have one doubt, how can we do the same with data from restapi .i.e. a json data. can u please help me in that.I can provide my json data from api.

Comment: to fetch from api, try using [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: can u please edit it in my question,i can provide the json data from api.I have done using Futurebuilder but its showing snapshot data has error.

Comment: Currently, your `_questions` is working fine.  To fetch from api you need to handle future, then you will get similar to this based on response, check FutureBuilder example you will get it. check more about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: instead of _questions, i want to load data dynamically in the widget provided above .